# How to convert long table to wide table in r?

Tags: r, pivot, data-manipulation

I am trying to format my data so that it is wide rather than long and I seem to be encountering issues transforming it from a list to anything that would let me change its form.

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)


A <- as.list(c("v", "w", "x", "y", "NA"))
str(A) 
X <- 5
G <- str_split_fixed(A, ", ", X)
G <- as.data.frame(A)
G <- G[-c(182, 183)] #irrelevant on example data my actual data is much longer
P <- G
P <- gsub("NA", "Z", as.character(P))#also irrelavent for example data
P <- str_split_fixed(P, ", ", X)
colnames(P) <-  c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
Titles <- c("Time_Modifier", "Times", "Scrambles", "Blank", "ID")
T.1 <- strsplit(Titles, " ")
n <- nrow(P)
n/5
L <- rep(T.1, n/5)
T.T <- cbind(P, L)

T.T.1 <- subset(T.T, select = -c(B, C, D, E))
T.T.1 <- subset(T.T.1, L != "Blank")
```

I have tried using pivot_wider() where I get this error

```
pivot_wider(T.T.1,
           names_from = L,
           values_from = A
           )
```

Error in UseMethod("pivot_wider") :
no applicable method for 'pivot_wider' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'list')"

I have also tried using pivot_wider_spec() where I get a similar error. which lead me to think that T.T.1 is being stored as a list; which low and behold it is. however, I seem to be unable to change T.T.1 into a data type that pivot_wider likes.

I have tried transforming T.T.1 using as.data.frame(), as.character and just about everything else I could think of or find.

```
T.T.1 <- as.data.frame(T.T.1)
pivot_wider(T.T.1,
           names_from = L,
           values_from = A
           )
```

Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript has the wrong type `list`.
i It must be numeric or character.

```
T.T.1 <- as.character(T.T.1)
pivot_wider(T.T.1,
           names_from = L,
           values_from = A
           )
```

Error in UseMethod("pivot_wider") :
no applicable method for 'pivot_wider' applied to an object of class "character"

any and all help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Actually `pivot_wider(data.frame(T.T.1), ... ... ...` worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pivot_wider` needs a data frame:

Therefore use `as_tibble` or `as.data.frame` before `T.T.1` which is a matrix (you can check with `class(T.T.1)`:

You will get a list. In case you want to see the list use `unnest` from `tidyr` package.

```
pivot_wider(as_tibble(T.T.1),
            names_from = L,
            values_from = A
) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(Time_Modifier, Times, Scrambles, ID))
```

output:

```
  Time_Modifier Times Scrambles ID   
  <chr>         <chr> <chr>     <chr>
1 v             w     x         Z
```

Comment: Oh, sweet thank you very much that is exactly what I needed. thank you very much!!